# Нужно перенести все вложенные файлы и директории в другой каталог. Команда 'mv'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Проблема в чем, суть в том, что я хочу перенести все файлы в директорию, которая является поддиректорией каталога:

Типа вот пример дерева данных в каталоге

|

- Файло-помойка
- ...
- Файло-помойка
- Директория в которую я хочу перенести данные допустим `a-files`

В чем суть я пытаюсь перенести вот так:

```
mv ./a* ./a-files
```

И у меня ошибка в том, что я же не могу каталог `a-files` сам в себя перенести и что с этим можно сделать? Есть ли в bash какой-нибудь аналог конъюнкции?

Могу ли я добавить как-нибудь конъюнкцию и директорию `a-files`,как исключение в исходные_файлы?

[image: Синтаксис]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это не ошибка, файлы у вас все равно переместятся:

```
 ~ $ ls
Music
Music1
 ~ $ mv * Music
Cannot move 'Music' to a subdirectory of itself, 'Music/Music'
 ~ $ ls Music
Music1
```

Comment: Да, вы правы у меня проблема была то, что у меня конъюнкция между командами была ( && ), а мне надо было поменять её на последовательное выполнение команд (;), чтобы все красиво в одну строку делалось. Почему-то при конъюнкции между командами выполнялась только первая, а все остальные что-ли занулялись при выбросе нестрогого исключения.